# Limit submit permissions based on cookie

Tags: php, html

I have some code which will submit some values to my database, I want guests to be able to submit once every 24 hours. I would prefer to know how to do this with cookie because IP restrictions will restrict NAT users.

Does it have to be in a separate PHP file?

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno ())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//post result to db
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? I don't see any attempt at using cookies in your code. And what does that have to do with Java?

Comment: for each visit, check if the cookie set, if set, then, it will be yours, if not, set cookie for 24 hours, then, no need to know IP.

Comment: that was a typo, the cookie code is what im looking for... im not sure how to do it.

Comment: Haha! I am an evil user and I will simply restart my modem in order to get a new IP! A cookie? I will eat it! The statistics will suffer from my evil actions, hahahahahahah! (sorry, could not resists :); just keep in mind that this kind of security is not really secure)

Comment: A more secure way of achieving this is to implement individual accounts, and try to detect people with duplicate logins. Otherwise, cookies and IP addresses is okay - it depends on what level of assurance you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what if user removes cookie or simply denies accepting cookies? He can send zillion of inserts in your database. A cookie is not a safe way to 'protect' something. Restrict it by IP+Cookie at same time or make some login system.

Anyway, do what you want, here is to set a cookie code if it is not set:

```
  if(isset($_COOKIE['somenameofmycookie'])) {
    echo 'you can not submit a form!';
  } else {
    setcookie("somenameofmycookie", $info, time()+1111111); //write in $info what do you want and set a proper time to 24 hours, more at php.net
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function is_submit_allowed ($form_name, $timeout)
{
    session_set_cookie_params ($timeout);
    @session_start ();

    $key = "${form_name}_last_submit_time";
    $now = time ();
    if (!isset ($_SESSION [$key]) || $_SESSION [$key] <= $now - $timeout)
    {
        $_SESSION [$key] = $now;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

if (is_submit_allowed ("vote_form", 24 * 60 * 60))
{
    echo ("Submitting...");
}
else
{
    echo ("You can only submit once every 24 hours");
}
?>
```

Comment: That won't work. Sessions don't last forever, and users can restart their browser and get a new session.

Comment: That doesn't fix anything. You're still using the session, which will be lost as soon as the user restarts its browser. You need a persistent cookie to implement that.

Comment: @JBNizet Session will survive browser restart if cookie lifetime is non-zero: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: Oops. You're right. I thought it only changed the timeout delay of the session. This has a serious side-effect though. I would not do that, and use a specific persistent cookie instead.